# How to restrict user ssh to ec2 not able to access s3 bucket accessed by ec2 application

Tags: amazon-ec2

The problem here is I have a s3 bucket (cross account). I only want the application I deployed to the ec2 instance to access the bucket (through ec2 instance role). But I still want, says User A (without any role to access the s3 bucket) to ssh to the instance to perform some debugging. I definitely don't want User A who can ssh to ec2 to access that S3 bucket. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure an ec2 role applies to the entire machine, so any user that has login rights would be able to execute requests using the role.

To avoid having to debug locally from the instance, you could setup log shipping and export metric data to cloudwatch logs/metrics. You can also setup AWS SSM Run command to allow execution of specific commands/scripts against the instances. Both CloudWatch and the Run command can be secured with IAM policies to control who has access to what.